# Arithmetic problem: forward declaration and always returning zero after division

Tags: c

### Problem Statement

I'm trying to write a util function to help me calculate time elapsed between two moments, and this function is put into a seperate `util.c` file.
However, whenever I try to access the arithmetic calculation through external function call, the result is always **zero**. And the code looks like this:

```
double timing(struct timeval before, struct timeval after){
     struct timeval result;
     timersub(&after, &before, &result);
     double res = (double) result.tv_sec + ((double)result.tv_usec)/1e6;
     return res;
}
```

I try to call `timing` in my `main` function

```
gettimeofday(&before,NULL);
usleep(some seconds);
gettimeofday(&after,NULL);
double salad_time = timing(before, after); 
printf("THE TIME used for a salad is %f \n",salad_time);
```

Now the weird thing is that:
If I simply do this, the final `printf` would always give me a `0.000000` as result.
As `timing` is defined in another `util.h` file and has its function code written in `util.c`, I simply include `util.h` and try to use it in my `main` function.

### My Research

I found many posts talking about similar problems, where performing divisions give **zero** as result, and the reasons were that people used integer division, and the results were somehow **rounded** and gave zero. Therefore, I added some type `double` conversion in my `timing` function, when I'm performing the arithmetic operation, as you can see.  But this does not help.

### My Tentative Solution

The interesting part happened when I put a **forward declaration** of function `timing` on top of my `main` function, and the whole thing just worked, and the calculation result is being correctly shown!
The edition looks like, on top of the `main` function:

```
double timing(struct timeval before, struct timeval after);
int main(int argc, char ** argv){ ... }
```

What is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show [mcve]. And the "Tentative solution too". In C functions are required to be declared before use, so that might be your problem, based on the "forward declaration" solution.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values? For this I also suggest you divide up "complex" expressions into smaller and simpler expressions where you can easily see the intermediate results.

Comment: Also remember to build with extra warnings enabled, and treat all warnings as errors that must be solved. Missing forward declarations is one thing the compiler can (and will) warn for.

Comment: If you "put a forward declaration of function `timing` on top of my `main` function, and the whole thing just worked", I suspect the compiler was using an implicit `int` return type for your `timing` function.

Comment: @FredLarson Hi, So although I declared my return type as `double`, it would still not work? Could you elaborate more on the implicit return type used by the compiler?

Comment: The compiler needs to see a declaration before it encounters a call. If you define it in one translation unit without declaring it in another where it is called, you're likely to run into problems like this.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall`

Comment: What does the declaration of `timing` look like in uilt.h? And is util.h included where `main` is defined?

Comment: @FredLarson So I would have this warning after compilation, 
" warning: implicit declaration of function 'detach' ", and `detach` is another function I declared in the external file `util.c`. So I guess this is the issue of not forward declaring ? And previously I'm also warned the same thing about `timing`, but now I'm not, (because of the forward declaration, I guess)

Comment: Implicitly declared functions (which were removed in the C99 standard IIRC)  are declared to return an `int`. Since that won't match the actual function you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @interjay Hi, `util.h` is included, and the declaration of `timinig` inside `util.h` is the same as what I forward declared later on top of `main()`

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your util.h, for example maybe the include guards are done incorrectly so the file is being ignored.

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hi, I believe that should be the reason. Good to learn something new. Thanks.

Comment: @FredLarson Thanks a lot. That clears my confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ANSI C it is possible to call a function that has no prototype. Compiler will assume the return value is 'int'.

To be more precise, the compiler will assume that the prototype is:

```
int foo();
```

This may explain why return value of zero is observed.

Anyway, returning double from a function of incompatible type is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hi, a quick question: so the declaration of function in an external header file is not considered a prototype? Do we need to forward declare a self-defined function before use, even though the corresponding header has been included?

Comment: @aProgrammingnoob, the header should be enough. Are you sure that the header is correctly included? Maybe the is a typo in it?

Comment: So the header  is named `myUtil.h`, and  I added `header guard` in the header file as `ifdef MYUTIL_H #define MYUTIL_H #endif`. The function declaration stays the same.

Comment: Just a follow up, I found a typo in my header guard. it should be `ifndef`, and I wrote it to `ifdef`. Now I fix it, and no more `implicit declaration` warning was thrown! :)